# Web api generating .rdlc report, passing data trough rest api

Tags: azure, api, rest, pdf, rdlc

I've built rest API where at first I generate .rdlc report and send it trough api GET method as byte array.
Another applicaiton calls it and gets byte array.

I return bytes like this:

```
  HttpResponseMessage res = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                res.Content = new ByteArrayContent(file);
                res.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                return res;
```

Works on localhost, but when I publish it on azure, calling same api method returns error code:
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: content

I've tried to set .rdlc report "Building Action" to Content, but it didn't help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is azure plan. Unfortunately, generating rdlc file uses GDI+, and shared azure resources disabled that option.